# `Check if a string is a date value` is a duplicate of `Detecting an "invalid date" Date instance in JavaScript`

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

[Check if a string is a date value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7445328/12860895) is a duplicate of [Detecting an "invalid date" Date instance in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1353684/12860895).

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7445328/12860895#comment51239323_7445328) states so and 6 users (including me) agree.

My flag was declined by one gold-badge user.

Whilst the question may be different, the solutions are cross-compatible.

Comment: Your flag was likely declined because 3 users with sufficient rep have [reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/30501940) the post in the Close Votes review queue and chose to "Leave it open".

Comment: "*The titles are different but they are effectively asking the same question and their answers solve both problems.*" no. You can do analysis of a string without using the Date object. Parsing as Date is only one solution, not all of the solutions

Comment: "*My flag was declined by one gold-badge user.*" no, that's not actually a thing that can happen.

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur gold badge users do not get to review flags.

Comment: *"6 users (including me) agree."* - 6 users... in the last ***6 years***, when over 400 _thousand_ people have viewed the page.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It ***ABSOLUTELY*** is not a duplicate.

One asks if *a string* is a valid date.

Other asks how to detect *a Date instance is invalid*.

These are two different data types, for a start.

Yes, *one* way of checking if a string is invalid is to convert it to a date. But that is only one of many solutions.

The two questions ask for different things. Period.

Comment: Beat me to it. Frustratingly JavaScript allows you to create a new Date object that is complete nonsense. The second question should never have needed to be asked if JavaScript threw an error properly when attempting to construct a Date object with invalid data.

Comment: @GregBurghardt today I learned. I guess that's an argument towards using date libraries until Javascript undergoes the same movement as Java has when it comes to its date/time API.

Comment: @Gimby [it is currently undergoing it](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/) but it is not complete.

Comment: I do hope they learn from .NET's `DateTime.Now` design mistake, and make `Temporal.Now()` a function and not a property.